# Homeomorphism between Schemes is Affine Morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a proper morphism between Noetherian $k$-schemes with property that $f$ - considered as continuous map between underlying ***topological*** spaces $X$ and $Y$ is a ***homeomorphism***.

My question is why in this case $f$ is already a ***affine*** morphism?

Attempts:
I intend to use ***Serre's criterion for affinity***:

Let $X$ Noetherian scheme. Then

$$X \text{ affine } \Leftrightarrow H^i(X, \mathcal{F})=0 \text{ for all quasicoherent sheaves of modules } \mathcal{F} \text{and } i > 0$$

Therefore it suffice to solve following problems:

1. If $\mathcal{F}$ quasicohernt how to show that $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is also quasicoherent?

   (here I know an argument only in the case that $f$ is already affine =) )
2. Why holds $H^i(f^{-1}(U), \mathcal{F}) = H^i(U, f_* \mathcal{F})$ for given conditions above?

Comment: Your second question is completely trivial, since $f$ is a homeomorphism and the definition of cohomology uses only the topological space structure.

Comment: @Eric Wolfey: Do you have a reference for the construction which you have in mind? In our class we introduced the sheaf cohomology as derivated functors of the global section functor $H^0(-)$ on schemes, so at first glance it's not really obviously that they only depend on underlying topological spaces.

Comment: Well, derived functor on which category?  You're right that this isn't obvious if your functors are defined only on $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules, but you can also just define them on arbitrary sheaves of abelian groups.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey: Yes, I guess I (partially) understand. Since they are given as ***kernels*** of certain injective sheaves we can indeed forget the additionally module structure. So we can indeed consider the category of sheaves of abelian groups. But also with this assuption I don't see that the dependency is reduced only to underlying topological space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find answers to both of these questions in Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*.

Your first question is Proposition II.5.8(c).  As a sketch of the proof, since $X$ is Noetherian, it can be covered by finitely many affine open sets $U_i$, and each intersection $U_i\cap U_j$ can also be covered by finitely many affine open sets $U_{ijk}$.  Now, the pushforward of $\mathcal{F}$ restricted to any $U_i$ or $U_{ijk}$ is quasicoherent.  But the pushforward of $\mathcal{F}$ is just the kernel of a certain morphism between products of these restrictions, by the sheaf gluing axiom (a section of $f_*\mathcal{F}$ over $U$ is the same as sections over $U\cap U_i$ for each $i$ such that the restrictions to the $U_{ijk}$ agree).  Since the kernel of a morphism of quasicoherent sheaves is quasicoherent, this implies $f_*\mathcal{F}$ is quasicoherent.  (The Noetherian hypothesis is used to guarantee that the products of the restricted sheaves are finite, since an infinite product of quasicoherent sheaves may not be quasicoherent.)

Your second question follows from the fact that cohomology of sheaves can be defined as derived functors of the functor of global sections on the category of sheaves of abelian groups on the space.  The category of sheaves of abelian groups depends only on the topological structure (not the ringed space structure), and so this definition is obviously preserved by homeomorphisms.  The equivalence of cohomology defined for sheaves of abelian groups and cohomology defined for sheaves of $O_X$-modules is Proposition III.2.6 in Hartshorne.  As a sketch of the proof, you can show that flasque sheaves are acyclic in both categories, and so you can compute the cohomology of an $O_X$-module in either category by taking a resolution by flasque $O_X$-modules.

Comment: so the argument that the category of abelian sheaves on a topological space is invariant under homeomorphisms is just because the assignment is functorial?

Comment: Right.  The key fact is that, if $f:X\to Y$ is a homeomorphism, then $f_*$ is an isomorphism between the categories of sheaves of abelian groups on $X$ and $Y$.  This statement is totally obvious once you think about what it means.  You have the same topological space, and are just renaming the points by some bijection.